# App crashes on Nexus 10 but not on Galaxy Tab 3

Tags: android, crash

I'm developing an android app at the moment. I contains a lot of images.
When I'm testing the app on a galaxy tab 3 everything works fine. On a Nexus 10 the app crashes very often due to outofmemory errors:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

How can that be as the nexus 10 has double the memory?

I'm loading the images with this class:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
Context context;
public List<String> imgs = new ArrayList<String>();
ImageAdapter(Context context){
    this.context=context;
}

public void setImages(List<String> images){
    this.imgs = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imgs.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
    imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), generateBitmap(context, imgs.get(position), 699, 699));
    imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
}

public static Bitmap generateBitmap(Context ctx, String path, double maxHeight,double maxWidth) {
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    InputStream bitmapIs = null;

    DisplayMetrics metrics = ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    maxHeight = metrics.density * maxHeight;
    maxWidth  = metrics.density * maxWidth;

    try {
        bitmapIs = ctx.getAssets().open(path);
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}


    o.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapIs, null, o);

    // The new size we want to scale to
    int REQUIRED_SIZE = 0;
    if (maxWidth > maxHeight) {
        REQUIRED_SIZE = (int) maxWidth;
    } else {
        REQUIRED_SIZE = (int) maxHeight;
    }

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int width_tmp = o.outWidth;
    int height_tmp = o.outHeight;
    int sampleSize = 1;
    while (true) {
        if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
            break;
        width_tmp /= 2;
        height_tmp /= 2;
        sampleSize++;
    }

    // Decode with inSampleSize
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o2.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    o2.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
    Bitmap originalBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmapIs, null, o2);

    // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
    int origHeight = originalBmp.getHeight();
    int origWidth = originalBmp.getWidth();

    double scale = 1.0;

    double tmpScaleHeight = maxHeight / (double) origHeight;
    double tmpScaleWidth = maxWidth / (double) origWidth;

    if (tmpScaleHeight < tmpScaleWidth) {
        scale = tmpScaleHeight;
    } else {
        scale = tmpScaleWidth;
    }

    int scaledW = (int) (scale * origWidth);
    int scaledH = (int) (scale * origHeight);

    Bitmap tmpBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBmp, scaledW,
            scaledH, true);
    originalBmp.recycle();

    return tmpBmp;
}
```

}

```
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992): Process: de.abcdesign.abcdesignkatalog2014, PID: 6992
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:587)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:422)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:700)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:638)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:367)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at de.abcdesign.abcdesignkatalog2014.Category.onCreate(Category.java:163)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-10 14:14:18.245: E/AndroidRuntime(6992):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Doesn't matter if it does or not. If you ever get an `OutOfMemoryError` 99 times out of 100 it's an issue with your app, not the device

Comment: Even though the device has more RAM, VM instances still run with a restricted memory budget.

Comment: Post up some code so we can suggest what you might be doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the image size using below code. it will overcome out of memory error for me
`enter code here`

```
            Bitmap myBitmap;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.outHeight = 50;
    options.outWidth = 50;
    options.inSampleSize = 4;

    myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

    // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bean);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the property `largeheap` set to true in manifest. Then you will not get this error.

However you should also compress images using `Bitmap.Compress` method

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. 
The problem is, when I add Bitmap.Compress to the class above it has no effect. I tried to apply it it tmpBmp in the generateImage function.